# Vuejs framework's elements not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, element, element-ui

I've installed Vue.js framework called [element](http://element.eleme.io/?ref=madewithvuejs.com#/en-US/component/button) but I'm getting this error.

[image]

I'm importing all I need to index.html and Reviews.vue file which only contains:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
 <el-button type="primary" round>Primary</el-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import ColorPicker from 'element-ui'
  import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
  export default {}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```

All I'm getting as a result is text "Primary"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this 'quick start' snippet [from the element github page](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element#quick-start) will put you in the right direction:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Element from 'element-ui'

Vue.use(Element)

// or
import {
  Select,
  Button
  // ...
} from 'element-ui'

Vue.component(Select.name, Select)
Vue.component(Button.name, Button)
```

Basically, you either load all the elements with the `Vue.use` syntax (which I believe will load all of them into your bundle, so you maybe don't want to do so if you're not using a lot of element components in your app), or you load element's  `Button` component in your component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
  <el-button type="primary" round>Primary</el-button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import ColorPicker from 'element-ui'
  import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
  // mind this new line:
  import {Button} from 'element-ui'
  export default {}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

</style>
```